# Centering a page layout on higher resolutions

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I'm working on a site which has some big images etc to show. On my screen, at 1024 x 768 resolution, it fits the screen completely, going from left to right.

However on my client's screen, who has a bigger resolution, he sees the right part of the screen as blank, and wants me to center the layout rather than have it be left aligned. (I have my margin-left set to 0.)

If I simply increase the margin-left, it will cause a horizontal scrollbar to appear on lower resolutions like mine.

Is there any way to solve this that will work on all resolutions? Or do I have to resort to using javascript which will detect screen resolution, and increase the margin-left if the resolution is bigger than a certain value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#wrapper { margin: 0 auto; width: 960px; }
```

this will horizontally center an element with id="wrapper", so if all your content is inside that element, your page will be centered

basically if you apply margin-left: auto; and margin-right: auto; to a block element, it will be centered horizontally

Comment: You could but it's not good practice, as you'd have to set width on the body tag. The body is expected to be 100% wide.

Answer (score 2):

Make a container element around all the elements you want to center and give it an id like `id="container"` then add a **css** selector to center it.

```css
#container {
  margin: auto
}
```